# Spark 3.1-java throws internal error while running in GCP - Dataproc cluster

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

i am running spark job in GCP Dataproc cluster with autoscale enabled. Spark command is configured to run 2 executers per node and 3 cores for each executor. I observed that it took more time than expected and also i saw below errors in log. As it took more time i cancelled the job.

```
21/08/30 06:24:15 WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 116.0 in stage 40.0 (TID 11855) (our_cluster_name-w-27.c.project-name.internal executor 273): com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.io.IOExceptionWithStatus: Error in response stream
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResultQueueEntry$ExceptionResultQueueEntry.getResponseOrThrow(ResultQueueEntry.java:100)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResponseQueueReader.getNextMergedRow(ResponseQueueReader.java:100)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResponseQueueReader.getNextMergedRow(ResponseQueueReader.java:106)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResumingStreamingResultScanner.next(ResumingStreamingResultScanner.java:78)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResumingStreamingResultScanner.next(ResumingStreamingResultScanner.java:33)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.adapters.read.BigtableResultScannerAdapter$1.next(BigtableResultScannerAdapter.java:63)
    at repackaged.org.apache.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.datasources.HBaseTableScanRDD$$anon$3.hasNext(HBaseTableScanRDD.scala:185)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$ConcatIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:224)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:755)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.DefaultCachedBatchSerializer$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.DefaultCachedBatchSerializer$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:79)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIterator(MemoryStore.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.$anonfun$doPutIterator$1(BlockManager.scala:1423)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManager$$doPut(BlockManager.scala:1350)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1414)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:1237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:384)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: RST_STREAM closed stream. HTTP/2 error code: INTERNAL_ERROR
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:524)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.async.AbstractRetryingOperation.onError(AbstractRetryingOperation.java:215)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.async.AbstractRetryingOperation.onClose(AbstractRetryingOperation.java:178)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.RetryingReadRowsOperation.onClose(RetryingReadRowsOperation.java:230)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.io.RefreshingOAuth2CredentialsInterceptor$UnAuthResponseListener.onClose(RefreshingOAuth2CredentialsInterceptor.java:82)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.io.Watchdog$WatchedCall$1.onClose(Watchdog.java:188)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.io.ChannelPool$InstrumentedChannel$2.onClose(ChannelPool.java:213)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.census.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:701)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.census.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:398)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener$3.run(DelayedClientCall.java:464)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.delayOrExecute(DelayedClientCall.java:428)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.onClose(DelayedClientCall.java:461)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:617)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:70)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:803)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:782)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    ... 3 more

21/08/30 06:24:15 WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 275.0 in stage 16.0 (TID 23961) (our_cluster_name-w-152.c.project-name.internal executor 165): com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.io.IOExceptionWithStatus: Error in response stream
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResultQueueEntry$ExceptionResultQueueEntry.getResponseOrThrow(ResultQueueEntry.java:100)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResponseQueueReader.getNextMergedRow(ResponseQueueReader.java:100)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResponseQueueReader.getNextMergedRow(ResponseQueueReader.java:106)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResumingStreamingResultScanner.next(ResumingStreamingResultScanner.java:78)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResumingStreamingResultScanner.next(ResumingStreamingResultScanner.java:33)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.adapters.read.BigtableResultScannerAdapter$1.next(BigtableResultScannerAdapter.java:63)
    at repackaged.org.apache.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.datasources.HBaseTableScanRDD$$anon$3.hasNext(HBaseTableScanRDD.scala:185)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$ConcatIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:224)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:755)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.DefaultCachedBatchSerializer$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.DefaultCachedBatchSerializer$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:79)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIterator(MemoryStore.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.$anonfun$doPutIterator$1(BlockManager.scala:1423)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManager$$doPut(BlockManager.scala:1350)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1414)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:1237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:384)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: RST_STREAM closed stream. HTTP/2 error code: INTERNAL_ERROR
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:524)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.async.AbstractRetryingOperation.onError(AbstractRetryingOperation.java:215)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.async.AbstractRetryingOperation.onClose(AbstractRetryingOperation.java:178)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.RetryingReadRowsOperation.onClose(RetryingReadRowsOperation.java:230)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.io.RefreshingOAuth2CredentialsInterceptor$UnAuthResponseListener.onClose(RefreshingOAuth2CredentialsInterceptor.java:82)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.io.Watchdog$WatchedCall$1.onClose(Watchdog.java:188)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.io.ChannelPool$InstrumentedChannel$2.onClose(ChannelPool.java:213)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.census.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:701)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.census.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:398)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener$3.run(DelayedClientCall.java:464)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.delayOrExecute(DelayedClientCall.java:428)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.onClose(DelayedClientCall.java:461)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:617)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:70)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:803)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:782)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    ... 3 more

21/08/30 06:24:15 WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 230.0 in stage 31.0 (TID 23664) (our_cluster_name-w-230.c.project_name.internal executor 278): com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.io.IOExceptionWithStatus: Error in response stream
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResultQueueEntry$ExceptionResultQueueEntry.getResponseOrThrow(ResultQueueEntry.java:100)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResponseQueueReader.getNextMergedRow(ResponseQueueReader.java:100)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResponseQueueReader.getNextMergedRow(ResponseQueueReader.java:106)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResumingStreamingResultScanner.next(ResumingStreamingResultScanner.java:78)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResumingStreamingResultScanner.next(ResumingStreamingResultScanner.java:33)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.adapters.read.BigtableResultScannerAdapter$1.next(BigtableResultScannerAdapter.java:63)
    at repackaged.org.apache.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.datasources.HBaseTableScanRDD$$anon$3.hasNext(HBaseTableScanRDD.scala:185)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$ConcatIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:224)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:755)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.DefaultCachedBatchSerializer$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.DefaultCachedBatchSerializer$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:79)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIterator(MemoryStore.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.$anonfun$doPutIterator$1(BlockManager.scala:1423)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManager$$doPut(BlockManager.scala:1350)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1414)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:1237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:384)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: RST_STREAM closed stream. HTTP/2 error code: INTERNAL_ERROR
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:524)
```

i am using bigtable and bigquery in that job. Job works fine in local. What this error means? How can i debug this issue.

Comment: Could you please share the code you are trying to execute, so that I can reproduce your issue?